# How to get List View?

Tags: java, android

How to get List View android studio.this is my code

```
public class StockSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
DbHelper dbHelper;
Cursor cursor;
ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stock_search);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.display_listview);
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);


    Cursor result = dbHelper.getAllData();
    final ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();

    //get the data to the list view
    if(result.getCount() == 0 ){
        Toast.makeText(StockSearchActivity.this,"Databse is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        while (result.moveToNext()){
            theList.add(result.getString(0));
            theList.add(result.getString(1));
            theList.add(result.getString(2));
            theList.add(result.getString(3));
            theList.add(result.getString(4));
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        }
    }

}
```

}

following code is my activity code for list view.is this correct.code is not working

```
//getAllData
public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  " + tbName ,null);
    return result;
}
```

Above code has been implemented in the database class.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: don't set your adapter inside while loop. Set it only once when you have all the data in your list

Answer (score 0):

Set your `Adapter` outside `while loop`

```
//get the data to the list view
    if(result.getCount() == 0 ){
        Toast.makeText(StockSearchActivity.this,"Databse is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        while (result.moveToNext()){
            theList.add(result.getString(0));
            theList.add(result.getString(1));
            theList.add(result.getString(2));
            theList.add(result.getString(3));
            theList.add(result.getString(4));


        }
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the below line

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

When you are trying to fetch data from database, it should be opened in readable mode like below.

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```